# How to convert flat file DateTime to Timestamp format in Informatica Cloud Services

Tags: informatica, informatica-cloud, informatica-data-integration-hub

Trying to convert the date value coming in from csv flat file (2012-04-03  3:43:00 PM) into Normal timestamp value (YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MM:SS - without AM or PM).

```
DECODE (TRUE,
is_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS AM'), to_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM:SS'),
is_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS PM'), to_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MM:SS'), 
ERROR( 'NOT A VALID DATE') )
```

Above function gives me invalid expression error, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Pls use this to convert to date-time first. Then you can convert to anything in char format.

```
1. v_temp_dttm1 =  DECODE (TRUE,
is_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'), to_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')
)

2. out_temp_dttm1 = to_char(v_temp_dttm1,'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

I tested above formula using informatica and here is the output. i used mm/dd/yyyy as output format though.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but how does this work for a date time with PM, can I add another statement in the Decode function (same as AM)?

Comment: Informatica needs either AM or PM. You do not have to check both. I edited the answer and added test result.

Comment: I wasn't able to add the above in a Mapping configuration task so instead I used this, however I'm getting an error "Invalid string converting to Date" Could you please help?  DECODE (TRUE,
is_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'), 
to_char(to_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM')),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')

Comment: I think you have misplaced a ')'. to_char did not have end ')'. . pls use this `DECODE (TRUE, is_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'), to_char(to_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))`

Comment: Still getting the Error message [<<Expression Error>> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date ... t:TO_DATE(u:DECODE(i:TRUE,i:IS_DATE(u:'2012-04-03 03:43:00 PM',u:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'),u:TO_CHAR(t:TO_DATE(u:'2012-04-03 03:43:00 PM',u:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'),u:'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),u:NULL),u:'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US')].

Comment: is it possible to simplify the logic with IIF - `IIF( is_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'),
to_char(to_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
)`.

Comment: Still getting the same Error message is [<<Expression Error>> [TO_DATE]: invalid string for converting to Date ... t:TO_DATE(u:IIF(i:IS_DATE(u:'2012-04-03 03:43:00 PM',u:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'),u:TO_CHAR(t:TO_DATE(u:'2012-04-03 03:43:00 PM',u:'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS PM'),u:'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'),u:''),u:'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.US')].

Comment: Why are you putting `TO_DATE` around `IIF` expression? Do you want a datetime output or a string output? It seems like you need a datetime so couldyou pls use this - `IIF( is_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'), to_date(Extract_LAIB_LastCCVRefreshDate__c, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS AM'))`

Comment: Thank you so much your last IFF formula with datetime output worked!!